# Elastic - Only return fully matching documents

Tags: php, elasticsearch, match, exact-match

Having the following dataset:

```
[
{
 "id": 234,
 "category": "shoe"
},
{
 "id": 44,
 "category": "shoes"
},
{
 "id": 49,
 "category": "blue shoes"
},
{
 "id": 48,
 "category": "small shoes with glare"
}
]
```

Category's mapping is set to text.

And making a query like:

```
$query = (new ElasticQuery())
            ->setQuery([
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [
                        "match" => [
                            "category" => [
                                "query" => "shoe size 22"
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
```

Elastic always returns me as first results/highest score:

- small shoes with glare
- blue shoes
- shoes

Rather than shoe.

How can i tell elastic that i only want documents whose match is 100% of category's content? (not query)

I mean, if my search doesn't contain "blue shoes", i don't want blue result to appear. I only expected to get shoe or shoe and shoes at max.

I can't use term, because as i said, i don't expect a full match with the query. I expect the matched documents field to be fully matched.

Examples:

> - Query: shoe size 22
> - Expected results:
> - shoe

> - Query: small shoes with glare
> - Expected results:
> - small shoes with glare
> - shoes

> - Query: blue shoes
> - Expected results:
> - blue shoes
> - shoes

> - Query: green shoes
> - Expected results:
> - shoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to achieve your use case. You can use [Percolate query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) to achieve your use case.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "category": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "category": {
        "query": "shoe"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "category": {
        "query": "shoes"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "category": {
        "query": "blue shoes",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "category": {
        "query": "small shoes with glare
",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
      "query": {
        "percolate": {
          "field": "query",
          "document": {
            "category": "green shoes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65787899",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.13076457,
        "_source": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "category": {
                "query": "shoes",
                "operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "_percolator_document_slot": [
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @FrakyDale please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: soz, i didn't have time to try it until now :(